# Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js)

Tags: node.js, laravel-8

in laravel 8 i have a problem when enter npm run watch
error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js)